# HKDF Android implementation

Tags: android, python, kotlin, cryptography, hkdf

I'm trying to implement key exchange with HKDF for key derivation. I already looked at [Is HKDF implemented in Java Cryptography Architecture?
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985661/is-hkdf-implemented-in-java-cryptography-architecture)
, however, I'm still not getting what I am supposed to get.

In python, I have the following [(src)](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/):

```
shared = private_key.exchange(ec.ECDH(), peer_public_key).hex()
derived = HKDF(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), length=32, salt=b'', info=b'', backend=default_backend()).derive(shared.encode()).hex()
```

This works for python and iOS (I have it implemented there too). However, Android is giving me trouble at the last steps. Can someone elaborate on HKDF for Android?

EDIT:
Existing Kotlin code

```
val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC")
keyPairGenerator.initialize(384)
val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()

val peerPublicKey = ... created from external data

val keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH")
keyAgreement.init(keyPair.private)
keyAgreement.doPhase(peerPublicKey, true)
val sharedSecretKey = keyAgreement.generateSecret("ECDH")
```

Thanks!